# Robust solution to vertically center navigation bar within a section environment without using absolute positioning

Tags: html, css

Note: there are already several questions regarding how one could vertically center content within a div environment either via absolute positioning, fixed line height, table display, etc.

This question differs because it 1.) emphasizes a flexible way to vertically center context, rather than using fixed values 2.) for some reason when these solutions are used with a section environment the result is not as expected.

So how can I vertically center the navigation bar in the code below?

```css
.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 115px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: lightgray;
  text-align:center;
}

.header ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.header li {
  display: inline;
}


body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <section class="header">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li>One</li>
          <li>Two</li>
          <li>Three</li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </section>
  </body>
  
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple solution is to use `transform: translate`

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qsfj2s9b/1/)

Stack snippet

```css
.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 115px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: lightgray;
  text-align:center;
}

.header nav {                           /*  added rule to vertical align nav  */
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.header img, .header ul {               /*  added rule for img and ul  */
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.header ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.header li {
  display: inline;
}


body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <section class="header">
      <nav>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/40/f00" alt="">
        <ul>
          <li>One</li>
          <li>Two</li>
          <li>Three</li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </section>
  </body>
  
</html>
```

Comment: interesting, most of the similar solutions use absolute position there....

Comment: @SumNeuron I know, this one allows you to not give away content flow in the same way absolute does

Comment: @SumNeuron And you can have an image in there too...updated my sample

Comment: Nice! What happened when it is resized to a small screen? S.O.'s code embedder doesnt work with screen resizing unfortunately....

Comment: @SumNeuron The question is _what do you want to happen?_ .... Added a fiddle to my answer to play with

Comment: what I would ideally like is as follows: an image (left of navigation bar) with a horizontal navigation bar that is horizontally centered inclusive as well as vertically centered. When resized to a small screen the image stays vertically centered, and the text wraps.

Comment: @SumNeuron Either add `display: inline-table`, like this https://jsfiddle.net/qsfj2s9b/6/, or `display: inline-flex` like this https://jsfiddle.net/qsfj2s9b/5/, it all depends on the browser support you need ... and if you can use `flexbox`, here is a simpler version than the one already given: https://jsfiddle.net/qsfj2s9b/7/

Comment: may I contact you via your email as the solutions - while working in the fiddles - are not translating to my code

Comment: @SumNeuron You may.

Comment: @SumNeuron Got it...will have a look later, its 9.15PM here so most likely tomorrow, hope its ok

Comment: I think we live in the same time zone :P

Comment: @SumNeuron Returned your mail. 2 main issues, `nav` had `width: 100%`, which it shouldn't, and SVG is too big, being set to 100%, hence mess up the height, so I added a wrapper (and I made some comments in the CSS file)

Comment: @SumNeuron It isolate the SVG from affecting the `inline-flex` (the `span` becomes the flex item), which doesn't always behave with images ... and I will reply your mail soon

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox makes this easy. Just add the following to you `.header` class:

```css
.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 115px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: lightgray;
  text-align:center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.header ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.header li {
  display: inline;
}


body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <section class="header">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li>One</li>
          <li>Two</li>
          <li>Three</li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </section>
  </body>
  
</html>
```

Comment: What if you wanted to have an image left of the navigation?

Comment: @SumNeuron Would you want the `<img>` centered along with the `<nav>`? If so, you could just place the `<img>` inside the `<nav>` element. I could potentially mock up an example in JSFiddle if you attach a link to the image. Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, next to the navigation but the entire thing centered. I tried using flex-box in my own code (not in the question, I went back to the drawing board) but including the `<img>` inside the flex-box `<nav>`  results in awkward overflow (as the nav drops below the larger image rather than underneath the text)

Comment: @SumNeuron Check this out: https://jsfiddle.net/d5xfkd8p/ . I placed the image inside another `<li>` element, and then applied the same flexbox properties to the `<ul>` element. That what you're looking for?

Comment: @SumNeuron https://jsfiddle.net/d5xfkd8p/1/ - Alright, it now wraps. Anything is possible with flexbox! It is flexible! I highly recommend this video, if you're interested in learning some of the basics: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G7EIAgfkhmg&t=628s

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox provides the simplest answer:

```
.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 115px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: lightgray;
  text-align:center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
```